# Get user email from Facebook Web SDK API v5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, kohana

I need your help.
I am using `Kohana 3.0.4` framework for my web app and i want to use `facebook` login so i am using the `Facebook` Web `SDK v5`. I get every information from the the user profile except the user email. In my login action this what i did:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'xxxxxx',
      'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email', 'user_birthday', 'public_profile']; // optional
    $callback = 'http://www.example.com';
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions); echo "<a href='.$loginUrl.'>Login With Facebook</a>";
```

then in the redirected action:

```
# login-callback.php
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '1200538793346947',
      'app_secret' => '3cf44820ffae5f16c8122174701a558f',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
    ]);

    // Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken entity.
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    //   $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
    //   $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
    //   $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
      // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
      // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
      $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=email,name,birthday,gender', $accessToken);
    } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $me = $response->getGraphUser();
    echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName(). ' ' . $me->getId() . ' '. $me->getGender() . ' '. $me->getEmail() . '<br />';
    print_r($me->getBirthday());
```

Please i need help because i want to also get the user email. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the wrong method. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphNode/5.0.0#user-instance-methods does not list a getEmail method, so it is not a method for a user object. (getEmail is listed further down, but for group objects.) Just use `$me['email']`

Comment: thanks man but i have used `$me['email']` but the program returned undefined index.

Comment: Verify that the user has actually granted your app the permission (debug access token, or call /me/permissions), and that the e-mail address is verified with Facebook.

Comment: okay i called `var_dump($fb->get('/me/permissions', $accessToken));` and the status for email permission displays **granted**.

Comment: but i still don't receive the email.

Comment: As i khnow Facebook Api doesn't show the email if the user has make it private already.

Comment: Yes, privacy settings can affect this in some cases as well. Your app should not expect to get an e-mail address from all users – they might not even have an e-mail on file with Facebook, if they registered using only their mobile. If your app _needs_ an e-mail address, then implement an additional step to ask users for it yourself if the API doesn’t return one.